# Expectation value of number operator for a state $W(f)\psi$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, vacuum, many-body

Let $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ be fixed and define the Weyl operator:
$$W(f) := \exp(a^{*}(f)-a(f))$$
acting on the Fock space $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}(L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})) = \bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3n})$. If $\Omega = (1,0,0,...)$ denotes the vacuum vector on this Fock space, then:
$$W(f)\Omega = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\|f\|^{2}}(1,f,\frac{f^{\otimes 2}}{\sqrt{2!}}, ...,\frac{f^{\otimes n}}{\sqrt{n!}},...)$$
and the expected number of particles in the state $W(f)\Omega$ is just $\|f\|^{2}$, that is
$$\langle W(f)\Omega, \mathcal{N} W(f)\Omega\rangle = \|f\|^{2},$$
where $\mathcal{N}$ is the number operator on $\mathcal{F}$.

**Question:** Let $\psi \in \mathcal{F}$ be arbitrary, how to calculate $\langle W(f)\psi, \mathcal{N}W(f)\psi\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard trick in quantum optics is to evaluate the action of the Weyl operator on the number operator instead of on the state. Typically the number operator looks like $a^\dagger a$, so in your notation I will assume we can write it as
$$\mathcal{N}=a^*(f)a(f).$$ Then, for all states $\psi$ and $\phi$, we usually have
$$\langle W(f) \phi,G(a,a^*)W(f)\psi\rangle=\langle  \phi,G(a+1,a^*+1)\psi\rangle$$ using properties of [Displacement operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_operator) that follow from the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula, for any function[al] $G(a,a^*)$.  The number operator simply transforms to give you
$$\langle W(f) \psi,\mathcal{N}W(f)\psi\rangle=\langle  \psi,(\mathcal{N}+a(f)+a^*(f)+1)\psi\rangle,$$ which you can compute term by term by expressing $\psi$ in the Fock basis. Notably, for normalized $\psi=(\psi_0,\psi_1,\cdots)$, we have
$$\langle  \psi,(\mathcal{N}+a(f)+a^*(f)+1)\psi\rangle=\sum_i|\psi_i|^2 i+\sum_{i}(\psi_i\psi_{i+1}^*+\psi_i^*\psi_{i+1})+1.$$